# Label inside Stack View

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to have this format inside my cells, but I can't figure out what I should do in order to stop errors from appearing. My guess is that the problem is that the text labels have intrinsic size? If I would only have, let's say, the `Name` label, I would have a warning which would say that it was expected a higher height for the label. Can you please shed some light on these problems?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @matt can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

You appeared to be having issues with Compression resistance and content hugging priority. A view with high compression resistance will fight against shrinking and in other words, it will prevent the content to clip.

Content hugging, on the other hand, limits the view from growing larger than its content.

You need to set labels compression resistance and content hugging priority accordingly. Set higher compression resistance value, max is 1000, for the view which you don't want to shrink and set others value < 1000 for other views.

In order to satisfy auto resizing requirement resulted from different screen sizes, you need to ensure that content hugging property is appropriately set for views. Some views can grow to satisfy the constraint requirements. Set higher content priority for the view which you want it to prevent from overgrowing than its content size.

Comment: Thanks. Now I am no more getting errors, but warnings which say that different heights/widths were expected

Comment: Yoy can safely ignore it as it is placement warning

Comment: @Idindu It works and I understand that it doesn't affect much but I am not really comfortable knowing I have that warning. There must be a way to resolve it, right?

Comment: Update your frames by clicking on Resolve Auto layout issues menu in bottom right corner, next to pin option and it will resolve the warning.

Comment: @Idindu I already tried updating the frames but there is no way all the warnings will disappear. In best case scenario, only two warnings will be resolved out of 4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117923/discussion-between-ldindu-and-toma-radu-petrescu).